# jQuery: Is there an event that's triggered by data insertion into a HTML element, say div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that I have a `<div id="notification">` which has empty content to start with. The server will ajaxly inserts some content into it later on. Is there an event that's triggered by this insertion? Thanks.

Note I am using jQuery as my js framework.

Comment: How are you inserting the data?

Comment: That's an adverb I haven't seen before: "ajaxly"

Comment: As SLaks said, we need to know the way in which the data is populating the div.

Comment: If it's AJAX, then the callback function is executed - within callback function you can do whatever you need.

Comment: @SLaks - I will be using jQuery.post(), in whose success callback function the .html() will be used to insert the data into the div.

Comment: @BoltClock - I see "ajaxly" as a synonym to "magicly" lol

Comment: The server doesn't "insert" content into your div.  The server returns data that your client code has to marshal into the DOM or client variables.

Comment: @Kenny - you are precisely right. But I think all experienced web developers on here know what I am referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can trigger a custom event:

```
function addContentToDiv(div, markup) {

    // NOTE: div is a jQuery object:
    div.html(markup);
    div.trigger('myDivHtmlChanged');
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('myDiv').bind('myDivHtmlChanged', function() {
        alert('content changed in myDiv');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [there is](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified), but you can't rely on the browser supporting it. Instead, you want to hook into the ajax call, perhaps via [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) or one of its brethren.

Comment: I set up a similar test, which kinda works in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/mKxj8/

Answer (score 1):

There is the global ajaxComplete event that is triggered by jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

> Description: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is an Ajax Event.

```
$('.selector').ajaxComplete(function(e) {
    // add bling
});
```

Comment: yes and no, be careful! as an ajax call against $("#NotYourDiv").load("/hello.do"); will fire the event on your original item as well.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to know I have inserted data using ajax, I setup up a custom jQuery event on the divs in question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#notification").bind("ajaxComplete", function(event){
     alert("updated");
  });

  $("#notification").load("/hello.html", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    $("#notification").trigger("ajaxComplete");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event triggered by that insertion on a DIV.  Change event will trigger on form elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are the DOMNodeInserted, DOMNodeRemoved, etc... events:

```
$("body").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) { 
    var insertedNode = $(e.target);
    ...
});
```

But, like T.J. said, these aren't exactly browser friendly. In fact they won't work in any version of IE. You can find a complete list of DOM events and their browser support at: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/